# Tkinter Dialogue box issues

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have some code like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Entry, Label, Text, Button, W, SE, simpledialog

app_window = tk.Tk() #root
name = simpledialog.askfloat('hello', 'What is your name?: ',
                                  parent = app_window)
age = simpledialog.askfloat('hello', 'What is your age?: ',
                                    parent = app_window)
address = simpledialog.askfloat('hello', 'What is your address?: ',
                                    parent = app_window)
```

Is there a way to stop the main window from popping up on top of the dialogue boxes?

Comment: Actually for anyone who read this, I found the answer, app_window.withdraw().

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @БогданОпир as soon as I can I will edit it, just on a deadline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP said, the answer is to use `app_window.withdraw()`. The `.withdraw()` function minimizes a widget.

Read more about it [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#wm.Wm.withdraw-method).

Hope this helps!